# Name of a person that is intolerant of stupidity

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

What noun or adjective would one give to a person that is intolerant of stupidity? A person that becomes annoyed, angry, or of very short temper when conversing or interacting with people of a lower intelligence?

For example:

> The man is very ***xyzxyz***; his son can't do multiplication very well.

or

> She is a(n) ***xyzxyz***. She gets very frustrated when people forget things.

I'm looking almost for a scientific/medical/psychological term. One that would fall into the same kind of group as words like haemophiliac, masochist, nihilist, etc.

Comment: A *mentalist* ....... heh, heh.

Comment: Rather than a single-word noun or adjective, I'd just say ***He doesn't suffer fools gladly**.*

Comment: That also works, but I am after a single term, almost for classification. For instance, I would put these people into a category of "xyzxyz-s" and not "People that so not suffer fools gladly".

Comment: If the person at issue has mastered the art of using “DUH” or eye-rolling to express their frustration, they probably fancy him/herself to be an intellectual, which of course makes them [a pseudo-intellectual](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-pseudo-intellectual-and-an-intellectual-1) or at least someone with strong pseudo-intellectual tendencies.

Comment: Your question is pretty vague.  There is a difference between specific mental incapacities of some sort, low IQ, memory problems, and simply being "clueless".  Which do you mean?

Comment: Less aspects of a person, more simply acts of stupidity such as forgetting something from a few minutes ago, failing to apply recently gained understanding, plain misunderstanding of something said. This could just be being "clueless" but could also be as a result of the incapacities you mentionned

Answer (score 4):

While it is neither a noun nor an adjective, the phrase **does not suffer fools gladly** has the meaning you want.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [**unforgiving**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/unforgiving) - not allowing for mistakes, carelessness, or weakness

> She is **unforgiving**. She gets very angry when people forget things.

But, possibly a [**perfectionist**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/perfectionist) - a person who demands perfection of himself, herself, or others.

> She was a **perfectionist** and not tolerant of the short-comings of others.

[dictionary.com]

Answer (score 0):

One can use *disdainful* here.

Disdain means

> to treat someone with contempt because they do not know as much as you do

Comment: But this is hardly specific to intelligence, right?

Comment: This I would argue goes well for intelligence, IQ in general. What do you feel?

Comment: I feel one can be *disdainful* for any number of reasons, and the OP could change his question to ask about "height" instead of "IQ", and your answer wouldn't change (which tells me it's not really an answer to *this* question, but a more general one, which wasn't asked).

Comment: This is a good answer, but yes I am being specific on intelligence and not knowledge. As Einstein said: "Any fool can know; the point is to understand."

Comment: Disdainful is too broad. What the op wants is someone with aversion to stupidity. Think of it as allergic to a particular thing. He would be more of a stickler who resents stupidity.

Comment: Fairenough, I am tempted to suggest `elitist`.

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary Think *elitist* suffers the same issue: not specific to intelligence. One can be elitist about wealth, for example, or music choices, or fashion, or circumstances of birth. Etc.

Comment: Is there perhaps a scientific/medical/psychological term as that would fit well into the context in which I would use this word. As in I would use it in the same way I would use words like schizophrenic, sadist, haemophiliac, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know a word that fits exactly what you're looking for. A (strange?) suggestion might be to coin a word from a person or character who is best-known for this trait. I would suggest a "Kingsfield" after John Houseman's character in "The Paper Chase".

I also like "dumbophobe".

Comment: Do you have any reference that can support your answer?

Comment: @Rathony - You expect a reference for "I do not know"????

Comment: Dumbophobe is actually catchy..haha! You can say a person who hates dumbness or dumb or stupid people has Dumbophobia... Also seeking for the correct term though.

Comment: Intolerance is not the same as phobia or hatred.

Answer (score 0):

**highbrow**

[dictionary.com definition:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/highbrow)

> 2. a person with intellectual or cultural pretensions; intellectual snob.

[Oxford dictionary definition:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/highbrow)

> A person [of scholarly or [rarefied](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/rarefied#rarefied__2) taste]
>
> rareified - Distant from the lives and concerns of ordinary people

Comment: I think your answer is the closest among all the suggested words.

Comment: This is pretty close. The Oxford definition is less what I'm after but the dictionary.com one is pretty much it.

Comment: @OlieAyre words change meaning slightly depending on context, so don't worry about slight discrepancies between dictionary definitions.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of coining the word using a known figure to represent it (like "Sadist" being after De Sade).

So therefore, I put forth a "Winchester", after the character on "MASH".

Answer (score 0):

That would be a person with low tolerance for mediocrity. Thus,  a person who strives for excellence. If there's such a word, that would be *excellentist*, but the word *perfectionist* seems close. Although,  the gap between perfection, excellence and mediocrity can be equally big. I doubt there's such a word since most people have low tolerance for mediocrity relative to the social and cultural standards, so there's no use for such a word.

Answer (score -1):

How about **overbearing**?

> "The man is very **overbearing**; his son can't do multiplication very
>   well.

I can tell you from first-hand experience, this word captures how I treated my son when it came to math: I was **overbearing** ... and I'm not proud of it.

From the The Free Dictionary:

> **overbearing** :
>
> - domineering in manner; arrogant
> - overwhelming in power or significance; predominant
> - domineering or dictatorial in manner or action
> - domineering; dictatorial; rudely arrogant
> - expecting unquestioning obedience
> - having or showing arrogant superiority to and disdain of those one    views as unworthy

Other applicable words include **domineering** and **predominant**.

Comment: This is a very nice word, but it's less a forceful (and definitely not arrogant) intolerance, but more a kind of tick, like one would be "triggered" in some sense by acts of stupidity, leading to reduced patience. A personal intolerance (not of one's self, but a feeling kept to one's self) as opposed to deliberate and forceful action against stupidity.

Comment: And you down voted this answer because?

Comment: @OlieAyre Thanks for the comment. A few thoughts. Several of the definitions mention *arrogance*, one even *rudely arrogant*. I consider being **overbearing** a personality trait, not a behavior triggered by a specific event. One can be habitually overbearing, i.e., habitually domineering, arrogant, dictatorial, superior, and disdainful of others, especially those considered to be lower, including those of lower intelligence.

Comment: I didn't down-vote it. However I will up-vote it as it's the best answer so far.